# Access a special div, generated by a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'll try to be clear. My problem is that i'm using php to get data from mysql. The table has more than one record. To show table records i'm using a while loop that as a condition has mysqli_fetch_array(). The records from the table must be shown in an echo(because i want to show them as html on the page), but every div generated from the while loop has a link to send me to another page, and if the client clicks on that link it will get the current divs information(after the table in database has more than one record the informations will be different) to be shown at the next page. Hope you understood it. Thanks in advance!

```
while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                            {
                             echo "<div class=\"row\">
                                <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                                    <div class=\"thumb\">
                                        <figure>
                                            <img src=\"images/extra-images/room-grid1.jpg\" alt=\"\"/>
                                            <figcaption>
                                                <a rel=\"prettyPhoto[gallery2]\" href=\"images/extra-images/room-grid1.jpg\">
                                                    <i class=\"fa fa-search\"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </figcaption>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                                    <div class=\"text\">
                                        <h4>".$rows1['Dh_lloji']."</h4>
                                        <p>".$rows1['Dh_Pershkrimi']."</p>
                                        <ul class=\"room-grid-meta\">
                                            <li>Max: ".$rows1['Dh_Kapaciteti']."</li>
                                            <li>Size: ".$rows1['Dh_madhesia']."</li>
                                            <li>Floor: ".$rows1['Dh_Kati']."</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class=\"retail room-grid-retail\">
                                            <span>
                                                <sup>$</sup>
                                                ".$rows1['Dh_cmimi']."
                                                <sub>night</sub>
                                            </span>";
                                            if(isset($_SESSION['Emri_Mbiemri']) != '')
                                            {
                                                echo "<a class=\"btn-3\" href=\"payment.php\">Book now</a>";
                                            }else{
                                                $error = "You must be logged in to book!";
                                            }

                                        echo "<br>".$error."</div>
                                        <div id=\"price_room\">".$rows1['Dh_cmimi']."</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>";

                                $count++;
                            }
```

Comment: so you have a list of data, then a user clicks on one of these items and is taken to a new page?  This page then gets and display that item clicked data??  as mentioned it needs a bit more to it, otherwise send the id of the item via a query string page.php?itemid=6772 etc

Comment: Will you also be getting the information data from database? Its not clear what is the problem, you should try to explain it by sharing your code.

Comment: I think you have to share your JavaScript as well to understand what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I've already made a solution without using javascript, thanks for the interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution for my problem and i wanted to share it with you guys. I gave a $count to the links defining every link the while loop generates...

```
<a class=\"btn-3\" href=\"payment.php?id=$count\">Book now</a>
```

After that i used a multidimensional array to store the current divs variable(in my case rooms price, the count, and the id) of the room from database...

```
$room_prices[$count][0] = $rows1['Dh_cmimi'];
                                $room_prices[$count][1] = $count;
                                $room_prices[$count][2] = $rows1['ID_Dhoma'];
```

After the client click a specific link he will get the id so i can make a search at my multidimensional array for the price and the id of that room..

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                            {
                                    if($_GET['id'] == $room_prices[$i][1]){
                                      $sess_room_price = $room_prices[$i][0];
                                      $sess_room_id = $room_prices[$i][2];
                                    }
                            }
```

After i get these i store them at the global session variables to use them at the other page...

```
$_SESSION['Rooms_Price'] = $sess_room_price;
                    $_SESSION['Rooms_ID'] = $sess_room_id;
```

So this did the work for me... Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need at least your custom counter, that will be increment inside cycle, and set div's id based on this counter plus use it in generated link

Comment: The problem is that i cant use the div's counter as an array index in php. Cant use a javascript variable in php.

Comment: @ArlindHajdari why not? You can write something like `<div id="special-item-<?php echo $count; ?>">` and later access it with JavaScript using `getElemenyById('special-item-1');` or jQuery `$('#special-item-1')`

Comment: The problem is that i have to put the count at the php multidimensional array as an index, so it wont work. By the way I've found a solution for it. Thanks for the help :)